# Exception thrown while using logback/slf4j/java

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I am using `slf4j 1.7.2 api` jar. Logback version is 0.9.28 (core & classic). Java `jdk 1.6`.
I received following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:112)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:469)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:425)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:629)
    at com.amginetech.rsa.controller.AgentController.getByUser(AgentController.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

P.S. [Exception thrown while using logback/slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165633/exception-thrown-while-using-logback-slf4j) was been wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a more recent version of logback should solve the problem.