# Jetty, websockets and java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: websocket, jetty

I'm trying to run a Camel Server on Jetty 8.1. The WebSocket run correctly, I can see the print in Init() methode.

But since I set a WebSocket in my camel-context.txt:

```
<to uri="ws:JettyAlarmEndpoint"/>
```

I've this error in Jetty console:

```
[                          main] ContextLoader                  ERROR Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springfr
amework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]: problem with handler cla
ss file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
```

I.e: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;**

My WebSocket is simple as you can see:

```
package com.thales.ktdscis.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket.OnTextMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet;

import com.thales.ktdscis.utils.JSONUtils;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RiaWebSocket
 */
@WebServlet("/test")
public class JettyEndpoint extends WebSocketServlet {
    private static final long           serialVersionUID    = -1798046558917516877L;
    public static final boolean         DEBUG               = false;

    public final Set<ObserverWebSocket> users               = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<ObserverWebSocket>();

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
            System.out.println(" XXX JettyEndpoint().Init() XXX ");
        super.init();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest arg0, String arg1) {
        return new ObserverWebSocket(users);
    }

    public class ObserverWebSocket implements OnTextMessage {
        private Connection              connection;
        private Set<ObserverWebSocket>  users;

        public ObserverWebSocket(Set<ObserverWebSocket> users) {
            this.users = users;

        }

        public void onMessage(String message) {
            System.out.println("Message received : " + message);
            unicast(message);
        }

        private void unicast(String message) {
            try {
                this.connection.sendMessage(message);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void broadcast(String message) {
            for (ObserverWebSocket user : users) {
                try {
                    user.connection.sendMessage(message);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Connection connection) {
            this.connection = connection;
            users.add(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int closeCode, String message) {
            users.remove(this);
        }

    }

}
```

I've read lot of forum about missing .jar in classpath, I've got the "missing method" in my classpath when I open the lib .jar.

I've try with javax.WebSocket and import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket. Always the same error. I would like to run a specific method in my webSocket each time the "to" route is called. Ideally, send a message to the clients list.

Have you got any idea ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception thrown while using logback/slf4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165633/exception-thrown-while-using-logback-slf4j)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple slf4j jars in your classpath.  Likely with mismatching versions.

This has been answered already in Stack Overflow: [Exception thrown while using logback/slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7165633/775715)

Comment: I've got 3 .jar related to log :
- log4j-1.2.16
- slf4j-api-1.6.1
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4

Comment: You have a mismatch in versions.  `slf4j-api.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12.jar` should match each other.  And you should use the `log4j.jar` version that `slf4j-log4j12.jar` was built against.  Example of valid pairings: `slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar` + `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar` + `log4j-1.2.17.jar`. (I just used the information in search.maven.org to find this out)