# Where is the slf4j binding?

Tags: maven, slf4j, slf4j-api

I want to configure logging correctly in my project and removed the omnipresent warning

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/richter/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.8/logback-classic-1.1.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/richter/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.2-b06/glassfish-embedded-all-3.2-b06.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

by excluding logging implementations through Maven `exclusions`. Now, I ended up with

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
```

The referenced website paragraph doesn't contain any hints what to do and existing questions, like [Exception thrown while using logback/slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165633/exception-thrown-while-using-logback-slf4j), suggest to do what I did afaik. My `mvn dependency:tree` is now

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ project1-web ---
[INFO] richtercloud:project1-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- richtercloud:project1-jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jscience:jscience:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javolution:javolution:jar:5.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:6.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.noggit:noggit:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- richtercloud:message-handler:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.getsentry.raven:raven:jar:7.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- richtercloud:message-handler-raven-bug-handler:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.glxn:qrgen:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.zxing:javase:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.barcode4j:barcode4j-light:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- richtercloud:validation-tools:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.httpunit:httpunit:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- rhino:js:jar:1.6R5:test
[INFO] |  +- nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:0.9.5:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.jtidy:jtidy:jar:r938:test
[INFO] |  \- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.1:test
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee:jar:2.0.0-alpha-10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-10:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.jsfunit:jsfunit-arquillian:jar:2.0.0.Beta3-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.jsfunit:jboss-jsfunit-core:jar:2.0.0.Beta3-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.8:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.8:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.14:test
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0-alpha-10:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee:jar:2.0.0-alpha-10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-10:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:test
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.7.0RC4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.7.0RC4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.7.0RC4:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.7.0RC4:test
[INFO] |        \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:1.7.0RC4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.7.0RC4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.7.0RC4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.7.5:test
[INFO] |     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] |     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.5:test
[INFO] +- net.sf.jmimemagic:jmimemagic:jar:0.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:jar:3.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.bitbucket.cowwoc:diff-match-patch:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.rauschig:jarchivelib:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-cdi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-ejb:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-resource:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:jar:3.2-b06:test
[INFO] \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:runtime
[INFO]    \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:runtime
[INFO]       \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:runtime
```

I need `slf4j-api` in order to be able to compile the project. Where is the old API request coming from?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/richter/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.8/logback-classic-1.1.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/richter/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.2-b06/glassfish-embedded-all-3.2-b06.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> ```

It said quite clear, you have slf4j bingding in both glassfish-embedded-all-3.2-b06.jar and logback-classic-1.1.8.jar.

Logback should be what you really need to print the log. But `org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class` in glassfish jar also can implenment slf4j logging api.

So, what you should do is exclude glassfish-embedded-all. If you really need it ,you should include some other version of glassfish-embedded, not `-all` jar. Or at least, you can just remove org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class in glassfish-embedded-all.jar